# MS Access 2007 .accdb extremely slow

Tags: ms-access-2007

My company will be upgrading from Access 97 databases to Access 2007.  I have created an .accdb file and have imported the objects from the Access 97 .mdb file.  The problem now I see is that even clicking on a button that just opens a form (no significant code behind it) takes 5 min.  Going into a design mode for a form takes like 3 min.  What could be wrong here?

I compared this with the MDE version of this file that I created and no problem.  Clicking on the button, the form loads right away.  But this should not be happening just because it's an .accdb file.  Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Before you import any objects have you compacted and repaired and cleaned your database?
Also is your data split between the forms, reports, etc.  In addition, do you have an MDB BE (back end) that has tables and the MDB FE (front end) has only a link to the tables.  If you don't you may want to consider it.  First try a compact and repair from the tools menu.

Comment: JonH, I had compacted and repaired and also the .mdb database is pretty clean. Our backend is SQL2005. Actually, the slowness going into design mode and loading seems to happen with only this particular form. No subform on it.  It's just got bunch of buttons and date criteria for pulling up reports.  The same form runs fine in Access 97.  Deleted the form and reimported and the same thing. If I create a brand new .accdb and just import this form with nothing else, then it works fine.

Comment: That is access for you.  I've run into similiar things in the past.  Sorry I don't have a better answer.